# What if Google Maps Url Scheme is Already registered by Another App

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I want to open google maps with a coordinate and the problem is that the scheme comgooglemaps is already registered for another app (!!!) and when i try to launch it , the other apps is launched ! , so how can I open google maps now ? 
Im currently using this method

```
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "comgooglemaps://?center=\(latitude),\(longitude)&zoom=14&views=traffic&q=loc:\(latitude),\(longitude)")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            print("Can't use comgooglemaps://")
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:\(latitude),\(longitude)&zoom=14&views=traffic")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
```

which the if is true but the other app is openned comgooglemaps key and googlechromes is listed in info.plist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing your app can do. If two apps register the same custom URL scheme, iOS will open one of them. A third app has no way to know that there is more than one app with the same registered URL scheme. A third app simply makes the request. It can't know which of the two is actually launched nor can it specify which of the two to launch.

None of this is specific to the Goole Maps custom URL scheme. Sadly, Apple makes no attempt to ensure that apps have a unique custom URL scheme.

Comment: Such a shame for both apple and the app , and its a famous app in my country so cant tell customers to unistall it  , currently using comgooglemaps-x-callback works fine for now

Comment: Personally, I think this other app is being bad for registering the same URL scheme as Google maps. They really should not be doing that. I bet if someone informed Google (or even Apple), the other company might be forced to fix it.

Comment: I've emailed the company for now , that would be Plan B if they didn't fix it , thanks anyway for your information